# Devilbox .ini file is not recognized

Tags: php, linux, docker, devilbox

I'd like to enable debugging on my devilbox server, on Fedora 39.

I have written a `devilbox-php.ini` configuration in `cfg/php-ini-8.2`:

```
; ############################################################
; # Devilbox php.ini: Xdebug example
; ############################################################
;
; Information
; -----------
; * Do not edit this file (it belongs to git)
; * This file show a possible Xdebug example configuration
; * If this file is enabled, it will overwrite the current Xdebug settings
;
; How to enable?
; --------------
; * Copy this file to another file with ".ini" extension
; * Only files with ".ini" extensions will be applied by PHP



;
; PHP.ini configuration
;
[PHP]

; Xdebug
; https://3.xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide
; Use these settings to enable Xdebug for PHP
; Make sure to read up on Xdebug some settings might significantly slow down requests.
; The following is just an example configuration and should be adjusted
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.remote_log=/var/log/php/xdebug.log
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0

; vim: set ft=dosini:
```

but when I run `docker exec devilbox-php-1 php --ini` I don't see my config file in the list, only the default ones:

```
└─▪ docker exec devilbox-php-1 php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php
Loaded Configuration File:         (none)
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/devilbox-runtime-sendmail.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/devilbox-runtime-timezone.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-amqp.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-apcu.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-bcmath.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-bz2.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-calendar.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-dba.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-enchant.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-exif.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-gd.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-gettext.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-gmp.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-igbinary.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-imagick.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-imap.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-intl.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-ldap.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-lz4.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-lzf.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-memcache.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-memcached.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-mongodb.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-msgpack.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-mysqli.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-oauth.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-opcache.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-pcntl.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-pdo_dblib.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-pdo_firebird.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-pdo_mysql.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-pdo_oci.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-pdo_pgsql.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-pgsql.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-pspell.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-redis.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-shmop.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-snmp.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-soap.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-sockets.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-sodium.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-sysvmsg.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-sysvsem.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-sysvshm.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-tidy.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-uploadprogress.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-uuid.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xlswriter.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xsl.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-yaml.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-zip.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-zstd.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xxx-devilbox-default-php.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/yyy-devilbox-user-runtime-devilbox-php.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/zzz-entrypoint-logfiles.ini
```

Also, the debugger isn't working obviously. According to the [documentation](https://devilbox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration-files/php-ini.html): `The file must end by .ini in order to be sourced by the PHP-FPM server.`, which is obviously satisfied. Running `docker exec devilbox-php-1 ls -la /etc/php-custom.d/`, I can see the file in question:

```
└─▪ docker exec devilbox-php-1 ls -la /etc/php-custom.d/
total 16
drwxr-xr-x. 1 devilbox devilbox  158 Jan 17 14:22 .
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root     root      290 Jan 17 14:15 ..
-rw-r--r--. 1 devilbox devilbox    0 Jan  3 11:49 .keepme
-rw-r--r--. 1 devilbox devilbox  838 Jan  3 11:49 README.md
-rw-r--r--. 1 devilbox devilbox 1101 Jan 17 14:14 devilbox-php.ini
-rw-r--r--. 1 devilbox devilbox 1544 Jan  3 11:49 devilbox-php.ini-default
-rw-r--r--. 1 devilbox devilbox 1065 Jan 17 14:22 devilbox-php.ini-xdebug
```

Comment: It's looking for additional ini files in `/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d`, it's not configured to look in `/etc/php-custom.d/`

Comment: then why is the it putting the configurations there?

Comment: That may be a question for the Devilbox devs